# Unir mutiples split en una sola variable

Tags: jquery, split

Estoy intentando crear un split de varias `variables`

```
var x = canales.split(',') 
output: (2) ["especialista", "propio"]
```

pero he intentado agregarle a ese mismo split más datos, ya intente usar:

```
globArr = []
var x = canales.split(',') 
var y = regiones.split(',')
globArr.push(x)
globArr.push(y)

output:
["especialista", "propio"]
["sur", "centro", "occidente"]
```

no me sirve debido a que quiero todo en un solo array deberia ser así:

```
["especialista", "propio","sur", "centro", "occidente"]
```

**¿alguien sabe que puedo hacer?**

Comment: regiones y canales que valen inicialmente?

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar la función concat, pues te permite agregar elementos y arreglos a tu arreglo como elementos:

```js
var a = ["1", "2", "3"];
var b = ["sur", "centro", "occidente"];
console.log(a.concat(b));
```